# The properties of $c_{00}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I am new to functional analysis. I wondering what properties of $c_{00}$ have.

In particular, I am wondering:

1. Why is $c_{00}$ is not closed in $\ell_p$ for $p\in[1,\infty]$.
2. What does the dual space of $c_{00}$ look like?
3. Why the dual space of $c_{00}$ is reflexive?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For all this note that $\ell^p(\Bbb N)$ has a Schauder basis given by the sequences $(e_n)_{k\in\Bbb N} = \delta_{kn}$. The linear span of these sequences is $c_{00}$, the closure of the span is $\ell^p(\Bbb N)$. So you have $c_{00}\subset \ell_p$ is dense. The dual of $c_{00}$ (if given $p$-norm) is thus the dual of $\ell^p$.

Comment: @s.harp I am sorry I am not familiar with Schauder basis. Can you be more specific on why $c_{00}$ is dense? Thank you!

Comment: A Schauder basis for a normed linear space $X$ is a linearly independent $B\subset X$ such that  for each $v\in X$ there is a $unique$ collection $(s_{v,b})_{b\in B}$ of (real or complex) scalars such that $v=\sum_{b\in B}b\cdot s_{v,b}.$  If $X$ is infinite-dimensional and separable then  $B=\{b_n: n\in \Bbb N\},$ where $b_n\ne b_m$ when $n\ne m,$ and for each $v\in X$ there is a unique sequence $(v_n)_{n\in \Bbb N} =(s_{b_n,v})_{n\in \Bbb N}$ of scalars such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|v- \sum_{j=1}^nb_nv_n\|=0.$

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment: For example a Hilbert-space basis for a Hilbert space is a type of Schauder basis. ...  Also, if $X$ is a finite-dimensional normed linear space, a Schuader basis is the same thing as a vector-space (Hamel) basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

The sequence
$$
(u_n)=\begin{cases}
1/k^{2/p} & 1\le k \le n\\
0 & k>n
\end{cases}$$
is a sequence of elements of $c_{00}$ that is converging in $\ell_p$ to the sequence $(1/k^{2/p})$ that is not in $c_{00}$. Hence $c_{00}$ is not closed.

For the other questions, see the commentS of [s.sharp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/152424/s-harp) above.